# Download files from Amazon S3 with Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I have a Django app that allows users to download MP3 files that they purchased and these MP3 files are hosted in Amazon S3. How can I force a download when users click a "download" button without allowing them to see the original link (to Amazon)? 
I have a view that downloads the file but the file is corrupt.
Here is how it looks like:

```
def download(request):
    filename = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/skempi/Ihsahn/04-emancipation-qtxmp3.mp3'
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition']='attachment;filename="%s"'%filename
    response["X-Sendfile"] = filename
    return response
```

Comment: Have you check this out? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=257743

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want the files to be downloadable, set ACL to be private (only accessible via your account). Your users will be still able to download file is you provide them with signed URL. When you sign a URL, you generate token with expire time. You can set it to something reasonable as 10 minutes. Use [Amazon Web Services interface for Python — Boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/).

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('your_bucket')
s3_file_path = bucket.get_key('path/to/file')
url = s3_file_path.generate_url(expires_in=600) # expiry time is in seconds

return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Note, that this is safe, as token is only valid only for one request method (GET by default) and only for one file. So there is no risk of someone reusing the token for example download other files or manipulate the file given.

Comment: I tried this but after `bucket = conn.get_bucket('my_bucket')` I get a `S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden` error and in the message tag there is `The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.`

Comment: @Mohamed: the time on your local machine is out of sync. You should set up automatic syncing using for example [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I try to use AS3 to upload files from the Django admin panel, do you think the issue is still with the time being out of sync

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been struggling with this for a few hours now.

Comment: @MohamedTurki: you probably have some issue with timezone setup on your machine.

Comment: is there a way to deliver more then one file at a time?

Comment: No, only one file at a time.  Many browsers don't support multi-file downloads.  You can either ZIP them up or do some solution where you trigger multiple downloads via JS.

Answer (score 10):

I couldn't easily find anywhere that specified how to do this and ended up back at this question time and again when I searched.  So

With django-storages using the boto backend, the way to do this is something like

```
filepath = settings.MEDIA_DIRECTORY + file.name
response_headers = {
    'response-content-type': 'application/force-download',
    'response-content-disposition':'attachment;filename="%s"'%file.name
    }
url = s3.generate_url(60, 'GET',
                bucket=settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
                key=filepath,
                response_headers=response_headers,
                force_http=True)
return http.HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: I discovered that this is currently built-in to django-storages. Following your above example, this can be accomplished as: `url = storage.url(filepath, headers=response_headers)`

Answer (score 5):

The answers above are outdated since they use boto instead of boto3. This is how it is done with boto3:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), /
aws_secret_access_key = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'))
bucket_name = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
file_name = settings.AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION + '/' + 'file-name'

url = client.generate_presigned_url(
                                    'get_object', 
                                    Params = { 
                                                'Bucket': bucket_name, 
                                                'Key': file_name, }, 
                                    ExpiresIn = 600, )
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```