# File upload Amazon very Slow using Django storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, python-django-storages

I am using **Django-Storages** for file upload to Amazon **S3** but the upload speed is very slow.

Is there any way I can get nice upload speed ?

I am using

> > Django == 1.4
> >
> > Django-storages == 1.1.8
> >
> > boto == 2.6.0

Django settings:

> > > DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
> > >
> > > AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXX'
> > >
> > > AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXX'
> > >
> > > AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'XXXdev'
> > >
> > > AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False

Comment: whatsyourinternetspeed.com ?

Comment: We need your internet speed like Priyank suggests and we could also use how big all the files you're trying to send up are together.

Comment: Its 4 mbps download  and 512 kbps upload

Comment: Should I use Browser based uploads using Post, to upload files directly to S3, to speed up the uploads ?

Comment: The django-stroages boto connection seems extremely slow, same problem here, still looking for solution

Comment: This fix seems ligit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700890/files-served-unbearably-slow-from-amazon-s3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think django is influencing a lot in here.
you can upload or download directly from S3 via the browser and see it is also not so fast.
If you upload from EC2 to S3, the fastest way is if the EC2 & S3 are on the same region.
Also, The fastest way is when your using the closest region from you.
(PC ==> EC2 ==> S3).

I read once this article, was a nice one:
http://www.takipiblog.com/2013/03/20/aws-olypmics-speed-testing-amazon-ec2-s3-across-regions/