# Download multiple files from S3 django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is the link i have used ([Download files from Amazon S3 with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975228/download-files-from-amazon-s3-with-django?rq=1)). Using this i'm able to download single file.

Code:

```
s3_template_path = queryset.values('file')
filename = 'test.pdf'
conn = boto.connect_s3('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('your_bucket')
s3_file_path = bucket.get_key(s3_template_path)
response_headers = {
'response-content-type': 'application/force-download',
'response-content-disposition':'attachment;filename="%s"'% filename
}
url = s3_file_path.generate_url(60, 'GET',
            response_headers=response_headers,
            force_http=True)
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

I need to download multiple files from S3, as a zip would be better. Can the mentioned method be modified and used. If not please suggest other method.

Comment: is s3_template_path the same for each file you are looking for?

Comment: no, template path is different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay here is a possible solution, it basically downloads each file and zips them into a folder, then returns this to the user.

Not sure if `s3_template_path` is the same for each file, but change this if neccessary

```
# python 3

import requests
import os
import zipfile

file_names = ['test.pdf', 'test2.pdf', 'test3.pdf']

# set up zip folder
zip_subdir = "download_folder"
zip_filename = zip_subdir + ".zip"
byte_stream = io.BytesIO()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(byte_stream, "w")  


for filename in file_names:
    s3_template_path = queryset.values('file')  
    conn = boto.connect_s3('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>')
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('your_bucket')
    s3_file_path = bucket.get_key(s3_template_path)
    response_headers = {
    'response-content-type': 'application/force-download',
    'response-content-disposition':'attachment;filename="%s"'% filename
    }
    url = s3_file_path.generate_url(60, 'GET',
                response_headers=response_headers,
                force_http=True)

    # download the file
    file_response = requests.get(url)  

    if file_response.status_code == 200:

        # create a copy of the file
        f1 = open(filename , 'wb')
        f1.write(file_response.content)
        f1.close()

        # write the file to the zip folder
        fdir, fname = os.path.split(filename)
        zip_path = os.path.join(zip_subdir, fname)
        zf.write(filename, zip_path)    

    # close the zip folder and return
    zf.close()
    response = HttpResponse(byte_stream.getvalue(), content_type="application/x-zip-compressed")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % zip_filename
    return response
```

Comment: Sorry I edited it twice, this version should work, as long as the file_response = requests.get(url) returns the file correctly

Comment: Thanks, will try this out

Comment: Okay you may have to generate s3_template_path inside loop, let me know if it works

Comment: Hello, I tried to use this code but I'am getting this kind of error `'str' object has no attribute 'get'` . . btw, I'am using django 2.2 and python 3. .