# How to download a file from S3 in django view?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

The django view function downloads the files:

```
def download(request):
    with open('path','rb') as fh:
        response = HttpResponse(fh.read()) 
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename='+base_name_edi
        return response
```

This function downloads the files. But I want to download the files from S3. How to find the path of the S3 File so that this function works?

Comment: refer here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975228/download-files-from-amazon-s3-with-django

Comment: Have you considered to return a redirect to an S3 URL directly?

Comment: @KlausD. S3 url direct shows OSError at /download

Comment: Share your model that having this s3 object and full error traceback.